# ERROR: extra data after last expected column on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

When I import csv file I see the this error

> ERROR: extra data after last expected column
>   SQL state: 22P04
>   Context: COPY everyhighschool, line 1: "﻿B100005528,서울특별시,구암고등학교,구암고등학교,,,,,"

My table

```
CREATE table everyhighschool(
schoolcode varchar(10),
region varchar(20),
shortschoolname varchar(30),
schoolname varchar(30))
```

My copy code

```
COPY everyhighschool(schoolcode, region, shortschoolname, schoolname)FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\code.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a pretty clear error message if you ask me.. your code told the database to expect 4 columns of data and then you provided a file with 9 columns of data..

Just because there is nothing between the last 5 commas doesn't mean it isn't data!

Clean up the file in a text editor and try again

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.